# Getting the Error in my code when framing LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

```
var lastName = employees
   .Where(a => a.Number ==
      (dm.MTM.Where(b => b.MTT.IsManager)
             .Select(c => c.Number)
             .FirstOrDefault()))
   .Select(z => z.LastName)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Error Message:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'XXX.Models.Mt.MTM'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Comment: `employees` seems to be a table on the DB, and `dm.MTM` what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
int? num = dm.MTM.Where(b => b.MTT.IsManager).Select(c => c.Number).FirstOrDefault();
var lastName = employees.Where(a => a.Number == num).Select(z => z.LastName).FirstOrDefault();
```

But you should add a check

```
if (num == null)
{
    // bad things, don't execute second query
}
```

between the two instructions.

The error is because in an Entity Framework query you can't do "things" too much fancy, like the things necessary to calculate `num`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// Calculate the number outside of the main query
// because the result is fixed
var nb = dm.MTM
      .Where(b => b.MTT.IsManager)
      .Select(c => c.Number)
      .FirstOrDefault();

// Perform the main query with the number parameter already calculated before
string lastName = String.Empty;
if (nb != null) // if null no need to run the query
{  
   lastName = employees
      .Where(a => a.Number == nb)
      .Select(z => z.LastName)
      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You don't need to get the number from the database for each employee, calculate the value before running your main query.
This will be faster, less error-prone and better for caching.